# Alert sound for new messages

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is it possible to set alert sound for new incomming messages and notifications associated with my Ask Ubuntu account?

Comment: Possible a question for http://meta.StackOverflow.com

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Chromium or Firefox, try the [Desktop Notifications for Stack Exchange](https://stackapps.com/q/3780/6969) extension, written by [Rob Wu](https://robwu.nl/). A picture says more than a hundred words, so here is a screenshot (taken from the Stackapps.com site):

[image: screenshot]

I cannot remember hearing sounds, but it should be easy to implement. When I see him later this day, I will ask him about it.